# Ввести два значения и вывести их произведение на экран монитора. (через scanf, printf)

Tags: c, visual-studio

Все строки scanf подчеркивает зеленым и появляются ошибки. Исправьте, пожалуйста, что не так. Недавно учу с, пока валенок в этом деле.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    float b;

    printf("enter a:");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("enter b:");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("a*b");
        scanf("%d*%f");
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пробелы после `%`  не нужны. Выводите как `printf("a*b = %f", a*b);`, без последующего `scanf`. Да, я не знаю, может, я вас огорчу, но вы учите С, а не С++...

Comment: как понять scanf("%d * %f")?

Comment: ой, про с++ было к другому вопросу. опечатка

Comment: Вы просто гениально "исправили" вопрос. Если до этого текст был ну почти правильным, то теперь это... слов нет.

Comment: Дам вам совет - не менять текст вопроса (кроме грамматических ошибок), а то смотришь и непонятно - что за ответ, если в коде все верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

double a, b, c;


printf("enter a:");
scanf("%lf", &a);

printf("enter b:");
scanf("%lf", &b);

printf("%lf * %lf = %lf\n", a, b, a*b);
return 0;

}
```

Результат:

enter a:2

enter b:4

2.000000 * 4.000000 = 8.000000

Comment: Можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как убрать нули?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int a, b, c;


printf("enter a:");
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("enter b:");
scanf("%d", &b);

printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a, b, a*b);
return 0;

}

Comment: спасибо огромное!